DAU in the Play Console is always zero but on Firebase it close to 350
For my Flutter application, we have added firebase and getting the logs and other analytics data.
await Firebase.initializeApp();
FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

// FlutterError.onError = FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError;

//uncomment below lines for production
FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
};
 PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
  FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
  return true;
 };

I have a question,
DAU in the Play Console is always looks zero but on Firebase it close to 350 and more why?
We have added Firebase already and getting the data also then why this Daily Active users are 0, but we are getting MAU(Monthly active users)
